# Item in list in dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, conditional-statements

I am creating a battleship game, I have this looking dictionary with ships and coordinates as their values and they are all saved into a self.__dict dictionary object in a main class.

```
{'battleship': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], 'cruiser': ['E1', 'F1', 'G3'], 'destroyer': ['D5', 'D6'], 'submarine': ['I9']}
```

my code should place on the board "*" when the entry not in the ships coordinates and "X" when its in coordinates.

for some reason the code not reading the shot that it's in the values and prints the miss "*" shot instead.

`changin_line` variable, is the new line inserted in the game board with the mark included.

`x_index` variable, is the picked coordinates that referrers where the mark should be placed.

```
shot = "A3"
        
if shot not in self.__dict.values():
     changin_line.insert(x_index, "*")   
else:
     changin_line.insert(x_index, "X")
```

Comment: ``self.__dict.values()`` is an *iterable of lists of* strings. It can only contain *lists of* strings, not strings.

Comment: I had it before without .values() and still it did not match it

Comment: `values()` is not the problem.

Comment: Is the cruiser broken into two pieces? How can it be at E1, F1, and G3? Is it supposed to be on a diagonal with the middle at F2? I admit it has been nearly 50 years since I played Battleship, but I think I still remember the basics.

Comment: the G3 was a mistake, it should have been G1, fixed that, but still that is a minor issue compared to the main :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.__dict.values()` is a list of lists, not a single list of positions. So you're comparing a string to a list, and this will never be true.

You need to drill down another level:

```
if not any(shot in ship_pos for ship_pos in self.__dict.values()):
    changin_line.insert(x_index, "*")
else:
    changin_line.insert(x_index, "X")
```

It might be better to invert your data structure. Instead of using the ship types as keys, use the coordinates as keys:

```
{'A1': 'battleship', 'A2': 'battleship', 'A3': 'battleship', 'A4': 'battleship',
 'E1': 'cruiser', 'F1': 'cruiser', 'G1': 'cruiser',
 ...
}
```

Then you can test `if shot in self.__dict:`. And if you want to know which ship was hit, it's simply `self.__dict[shot]`.

BTW, `__dict` seems like a poor name for this variable. Call it something like `ship_positions`.

Comment: this mark " * " was set as a miss, hence when I tried an existing position and it gave that sign I thought it was not working.

Now I just flipped the sign and it works as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh sorry, I got the conditions backward